# ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID when accessing same hostname with different port

Tags: java, https, certificate, keystore, splunk

We have a splunk instance which is exposed to internet via say https://splunk.mycompany.com

When we access the above URL browser says connection is secure meaning all certificates are ok.

Now splunk REST API service is running on port 8089. So to access splunk REST API we have to hit
https://splunk.mycompany.com:8089

Whenever we are hitting the above URL we are getting certificate issues and browser is saying "your connection is not private"
Error is: NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

As I am still accessing the same hostname via https (and a new port) it should establish a secure connection. But why it's failing to validate certificate authority?

Edit: I have been told by the splunk team to take ther certificate of https://splunk.mycompany.com and install in the java keystore in the machine from where the REST API call is being made. They also told this is working for otheres. My question why it is even needed?

Answer (score 1):

You should enable SSL on port 8089 via server.conf file.
Have a look at the Splunk Documentation here: https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/9.0.0/Security/ConfigTLSCertsS2S

Comment: I have been told by the splunk team to take ther certificate of https://splunk.mycompany.com and install in the java keystore in the machine from where the REST API call is being made. They also told this is working for otheres. My question why it is even needed?